# fscanf does not read all lines in the file

Tags: c, scanf

```c
struct soundInput{
    char choice[16];
    char type[7];
    char sound[10];
    char sound2[10];
};

struct soundInput Sound;
FILE *read;
read=fopen("input.txt","r");
fscanf(read,"%s\n",Sound.choice);
printf(Sound.choice);
```

The fscanf function reads data from the file but only reads 1 line. Then the printing process stops. And it writes only one line to the screen. However, there are more than 20 lines. How can I solve this error?

Comment: wait 5 mins I'll give you the code

Comment: The `'%s"` format specifier stops at the first whitespace.  If you want to read more, use a loop or a different method.  Also, you will want to use `"%15s"` to avoid a buffer overflow.

Comment: fgets is reading all the data. What I need is to read 3 pieces of data in a row in 3 separate parts.

Answer (score 0):

You have traverse the file to read all the lines in the document

**use fgetc instead of fscanf**

```
FILE *fptr; 
  
char filename[100], c; 
  

  
// Open file 
fptr = fopen(input.txt, "r"); 
if (fptr == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("Cannot open file \n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
  
// Read contents from file 
c = fgetc(fptr); 
while (c != EOF) 
{ 
    printf ("%c", c); 
    c = fgetc(fptr); 
} 
  
fclose(fptr);
```

**EDIT**

```
FILE* filePointer;
    int bufferLength = 255;
    char buffer[bufferLength];

filePointer = fopen("text.txt", "r");

while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, filePointer)) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
}

fclose(filePointer);
```

Use this here this code reads the file line by line, here the line is stored in buffer

Comment: ReversePlaylist
PrintPlaylist F
PrintPlaylist R
PlaySong N
PlaySong P
InsertSong H Song_A
InsertSong H Song_B                                                                                                I need to read this kind of data. I need every segment. Then to write if else

Comment: then traverse each line of file using fscanf, and please give a little more detail of what you want to do

Comment: I am working on a code that takes the information saved in the input file and reads it, then enters it into the required if structure and processes it. If a text like PLAYSONG H is written in the input file. Go to the playsong function. It writes many commands line by line. Like PLAYSONG, REVERSELIST

Comment: In this assignment, it is expected to develop a program that will deal with editing the playlist and playing songs of the music player application. This program to be developed must read a text-based input file, which will be named "input.txt" and each line corresponds to the commands that need to be executed, and by executing the commands in this file in order, the outputs of the commands will be written into a text-based output file that will be named "output.txt".

Comment: should write in the format. In addition, after printing the output produced by the commands with output to the file, it should print 5 characters ("*****") as a new line to the output file.